# Why am i getting "UnsupportedOperationException" when receiving files?

Tags: java

I have a group assignment and whenever I receive files it says 
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

What does this mean exactly? And how can I fix/prevent it?

Here is one of the files I received for example:

```
public class Interleave {
// TODO: write your code below this comment
// You must write a method that will interleave two arrays,
// producing a result array.  The resulting array should begin
// with the first element of the first given array.
// For example, the correct output for the setup in main is:
//
// 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
//
// The test suite in InterleaveTest.java provides more examples.
// If one array is larger than the other, the extra elements should
// be put onto the end of the result array.  For example,
// if interleaving:
//
// first:  new int[]{0, 1}
// second: new int[]{5, 6, 7, 8}
//
// ...the result should be:
//
// new int[]{0, 5, 1, 6, 7, 8}
//
// If interleaving:
//
// first:  new int[]{5, 6, 7, 8}
// second: new int[]{0, 1}
//
// ...the result should be:
//
// new int[]{5, 0, 6, 1, 7, 8}
//

// DO NOT MODIFY main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] first = new int[]{0, 2, 4, 6};
    int[] second = new int[]{1, 3, 5};
    int[] retval = interleave(first, second);
    for (int x = 0; x < retval.length; x++) {
        System.out.print("" + retval[x] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

static int[] interleave(int[] first, int[] second) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: It means that your assignment is to implement that operation.

Comment: The best fix would be to implement the method, don't you think?

Comment: There are two methods: `main` and `interleave`. There is a comment saying "**DO NOT MODIFY main**". Now for the really important question: Which method do you think you need to modify??? *Hint:* It is not `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnsupportedOperationException` is more like `NotYetImplemented` or `TODO` or `InsertYourCodeHere`. Just remove the line with `throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");` and put your code there.